# find the limit of a sequence

Tags: calculus, limits

I try to find the limit of the sequence: $X_n =\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k} - \ln(n)$.

I try to find it on [WolfarmAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/), but It didn't reconize this limit.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean $X_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\ln n$?

Comment: @Paul: Yes. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited your post. Please check if this is what you would like to ask. Thanks.

Comment: [Harmonic Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html)

Comment: The limit is called the Euler–Mascheroni constant, but it has no known closed form, and this limit is basically its definition. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant

Comment: See also proof that [Euler's constant exists](http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/ProofThatEulersConstantExists.html) at PlanetMath.
More generally for any positive function $f(x)$ which decreases to $0$, the limit $\gamma_f=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n f_k-\int_1^n f(x) \mathrm{d}x$ exists.
See [Maclaurin-Cauchy Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Maclaurin-CauchyTheorem.html) at MathWorld.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euler's constant is $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty } \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k} - \ln(n)%$.it is very famous in number theory and analytic number theory.Euler's constant is open problem just we can show this series is converges.

you can look page 52 from [Introduction to analytic number theory, Volume 1](http://books.google.com/books?id=Il64dZELHEIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=apostol+number&hl=en&sa=X&ei=R0oQT_60HYTx8QPXn92BBA&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=apostol%20number&f=false)
 By Tom M. Apostol for more detail

Comment: bagben: It is not clear what you meant by *Euler's constant is open problem*. Perhaps you wanted to say that the question whether this number is rational an open problem?

Comment: Martin Sleziak: thanks I mean this number is rational an open problem

Answer (score 3):

If you need to show existence of the limit, show that $X_n$ is decreasing and bounded below.